# Community Licenses

Tags: licenses, community

I'm trying to understand the differences between the three types of Community Licenses available.  It looks like you can purchase one of these for a user that does NOT need to "edit" information in a SalesForce organization account.  Is this correct?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Which community license are you asking about? Do you already have a community? What do you want users to be able to "see, but not edit". The latter is the primary factor. With any license, you can prevent a user from editing records. It's primarily the object they're allowed to access that determines which license to purchase

Answer (score 2):

Internal User License :  Employee Community is an internal user License which has access to 10 custom objects and tabs.It also has access to Accounts and Contacts.

External User License:There are 3 types of External User licenses Which are as following:

1).Customer Community:This community is best suited for the organization which has large number of external users.A Customer community can hold up to 7 millions users.
2).Customer Community Plus:This community is best suited when there are unlimited number of logins for managing Customer Support.

Note:Both the Customer Community and Customer Community Plus are good for B2C Community i.e.Business to Customer Community.

3).Partner Community:Partner Community is best suited for B2B Communities.The Users of Partner Community can Read,Create, and Edit the Salesforce Standard Objects such as accounts,Contacts and assets.Partner Community Users also have access to Send Email 
And workflow Approvals.

Limitation On the Number Of Users:There is a limit on the number of users that a Community 
must not Exceed.If it does then the organization will have to pay Extra Charge for it.

```
                     Type Of Community                                         Number Of Users
                       Partner or Customer Community                      300,000
                       Plus                                                      

                       Customer Community                                        10 Million
```

Note:If The Number of Users are exceeds this limit then not only it will result in extra charges but 
  It will also degrade the Sales force Performance.Therefore it is recommended that users Limit
  Should not be exceeded.

For more details you can go to this link:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about internal users? I was told that you can use only [Employee community](http://www.salesforce.com/communities/pricing/) for your internal users and need a license for each user ($25 user/month currently and is the same as force.com license cost). With this license type users can edit Accounts and contacts and up to 10 custom object, but won't have access to Opportunities or any other standard CRM objects.
Salesforce tweaks often license types availability, access levels and prices, and just relesed this new one, with Ligting Clouds introduction. It looks like they simplified them, eliminated some with very few diferences (like enhancing Unlimited edition with Performance features, but assigning more expensive Performace license cost though)